# Copy SharePoint 2010 site collection/web application

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications, sharepoint-2010, sitecollection

I have a SharePoint 2010 web application with one site collection. I want to copy that site collection to a new web application on the same server.

I took a backup and restored it to a new database on the sql server. I then created a new web application with a temporary content database that I removed from the web application. I then added the restored copy of the original web app to the new web application.

The problem is the newly attached content database show 0 site collections, but there is in fact 1 single site.

I guess it has something to do with the id's? I have tried adding the content db both with and without assigning a new ID to the database.

Any idea how one can copy a site collection to a new web application on the same server?

-- 
Christian

Answer (score 3):

Try using import/export. The main difference between import/export and backup/restore is that import/export generates new Guids.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Use Windows PowerShell to export a site, list, or document library in SharePoint Server

You can use Windows PowerShell to export a site, list, or document library manually or as part of a script that can be run at scheduled intervals.
To export a site, list or document library by using Windows PowerShell

```
Verify that you meet the following minimum requirements: See Add-SPShellAdmin.

On the Start menu, click All Programs.

Click Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.

Click SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.

At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following command:
```